# Infinite Product of 1-1/n^4

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, euler-product

When I look at wolframalpha, I get $$\prod_{n=2}^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{n^4}\right) = \frac{\sinh(4\pi)}{4\pi}.$$

My only guess where this comes from would be the euler's sine product formula$$\sin(z) = z\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^{2}}\right).$$
But, this gives $\sinh(π)=-i\sin(i\pi)= i\pi\prod\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right).$ I've fiddled around and cannot manage to get an $n^{4}$ showing up anywhere.

Comment: You are on the right line using the infinite product for sin ... $i^2=?$ ... & $(1-\frac{1}{n^2})(1+\frac{1}{n^2})=?$ ...

Comment: My guess is you should get (1 - 1/n^4) by multiplying (1 - 1/n^2) and (1 + 1/n^2), perhaps by somehow multiplying two sine products (one with z and one with iz)?

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put backslashes before the function names you get the right font and spacing.  So \sin x gives $\sin x$ instead of sin x which gives $sin x$

Comment: (Did you mean $\sinh(\pi)$ instead of $\sinh(4\pi)$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Observe you have
\begin{align}
\prod^\infty_{n=2} \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2} \right) \prod^\infty_{n=2} \left(1+\frac{1}{n^2} \right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You already have $\prod \left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$. What do you need to multiply by to get what you are after? Can you create that with what you already know?